# How to override Strapi Admin panel endpoints?

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

In the admin panel - I have a content-type `products`, which shows me all the products in the database (MongoDB)

[image]

Suppose I would like to edit a `product` and when I click on the `Save` button, I would like to hit a custom API/ override the existing endpoint that updates my 
`products` collection!

[image]

Is it possible to customize or override the admin panel APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update(v4): Judging by the comments - this answer is now outdated as things have changed for v4.*

The Strapi admin(strapi-admin) and Content manager(strapi-plugin-content-manager) are defined separately.

If you'd like to override/extend the endpoints; do so by defining the functions you want to override like so:

Locate the controller at:

> extensions/<plugin-name>/controllers/<controller-to-override-name>.js

Example:

> extensions/content-manager/controllers/ContentManager.js

**Notice that the "strapi-plugin" part of the name was dropped!**

Example of how to override and extend in controller file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  
  //this is how you destroy count
  async count(ctx) {
    ctx.body = {
      count: 99
    };
  },
  //this is how you extend
  async aFuncThatDoesntExistInOriginalController(ctx) {
     //add logic
  },
};
```

**If you're extending you must add a mapping from route to controller & method**
To see which endpoint is mapped to which method in the controller check out:

> node_modules/<plugin-name>/config/routes.json
> node_modules/strapi-plugin-content-manager/config/routes.json

Some basic info in docs: [controllers](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#controllers), [customization1](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#backend-customization) & [customization2](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#admin-panel-customization) and [FAQ](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/getting-started/troubleshooting.html#how-do-i-customize-a-plugin)

Comment: hi, looks like your talking about the API endpoints that are generated when creating a new content type. I m interested in overriding the admin page endpoints. The endpoints that are hit when you update a content-type via the admin page :
Sample log: 
 [2020-06-17T08:00:33.185Z] debug PUT /content-manager/explorer/application::products.products/5e8cc069ca721f208dcd35b2 (68 ms) 200

Comment: I have been trying to extend content manager plugin for hours and couldn't work out why no changes were being applied. It was to do with me prefixing the folder `strapi-plugin` - as the documentation says to! Thank you

Comment: What about strapi 4?

Comment: Any idea for solving issue in strapi 4?

Comment: I'm no longer using it so I can't test. I suggest one of you add an updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on ghosh's answer. You have to copy also the dependencies on which `ContentManager.js` relies on to avoid any errors as follows:

```
extensions/content-manager/  
└─── controllers
|   │   -   ContentManager.js
|   └─── validation/
|       -   index.js
|       -   model-configuration.js
|    
└─── services/
|    └─── utils/
|       └─── configuration/
|           -   attributes.js
│   
└─── utils/
    -   parse-multipart.js
```