# How and where to send status code for response in strapi?

Tags: http-status-codes, strapi

I have developed simple posts endpoint and I do not know what to override and where to add status code. For example when some error happens I want to send `500` or when object created I want to send `201` instead of `200`.

How and where to set status code in response of strapi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [strapi docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/requests-responses.html#responses) on responses, it uses a [koa response](https://koajs.com/#response) object.
So you can do something like:

```
//controller
ctx.send({
    message: 'The content was created!'
}, 201);
```

You can apply your own logic and response by using custom endpoints or modifying the existing ones. These are some closely related examples of how to do that - [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633311/how-to-add-custom-route-for-user/62634233#62634233) , [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387941/how-to-override-strapi-admin-panel-endpoints/62409121#62409121).

Comment if you need more info

Comment: Wow, it took me a while to find this answer. I could not find this in the docs at all.